# Клик по ссылке с помощью PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Используя phantomjs получаю страничку.
Как сделать клик по элементу

```
<a ng-if="!progress.enabled &amp;&amp; !credentials.phone_code_hash" ng-click="sendCode()">
          <my-i18n msgid="modal_next">Next</my-i18n><i class="icon icon-next-submit"></i>
        </a>
```

На сайте при клике на Next появляется всплывающее окно.

Comment: Добавьте код получения страницы.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mouseclick( element ) { //расширяем возможности phantomjs, делаем новую функцию настоящего клика по элементу
        // create a mouse click event
        var event = document.createEvent( 'MouseEvents' );
        event.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0 );
        // send click to element
        element.dispatchEvent( event );
    }

page.evaluate(
        function(mouseclick_fn) {
            window.setTimeout(
                function () {
                    var element = $('a')[0];
                    mouseclick_fn( element );
                },
                2000
            );

        },
        mouseclick
    );
```